# Qual è il significato di "intrigato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> C'era: in fondo a un crepaccio di nove metri, già misurato da una corda cui era 
>   stata legata, perché scendesse a piombo, una pietra. La luce delle torce elettriche, **intrigata** dai cespugli che venivano fuori dalle pareti del crepaccio, batteva appena sul fondo.

Ho cercato alla voce "intrigare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di "luce intrigata dai cespugli" che appare in questo brano. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo caso ***intrigata*** vuol dire che la luce era ostacolata dai rami e faticava a raggiungere il fondo.

Il significato adatto per [intrigare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intrigare/) da Treccani è il seguente:

> **intrigare** v. tr. e intr. (io intrigo, tu intrighi, ecc.). – 1. Altra forma (soprattutto settentr.) per intricare, nei sign. di
>   avviluppare insieme, arruffare, disordinare e sim.: i. una corda; mi
>   si sono intrigati i capelli; e anche, ma con uso più esteso e più
>   efficace, nei sign. di **impacciare, ostacolare, dare impiccio, in
>   senso proprio e fig.:** tutto questo disordine m’intriga nel lavoro

Comment: Ero convinto fosse solo un termine dialettale! Sono sorpreso che Sciascia lo usi visto che è un termine settentrionale.